# Chrome incorrectly invalidating form input after jQuery clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, dom

I have an issue when cloning a from in Chrome. Note that this doesn't seem to happen in Firefox.

When I dynamically create an `input` and clone that and then append to the form it will not validate, but when I check the `validityState` object of the `Node` is says everything is fine.

I know the `clone` doesn't make much sense, but it's a reduced testcase from what I require. Are there any solutions to ensure the DOM data is copied over correctly?

Javascript:

```
$('<input type="text" required="required" />').val('08').clone().appendTo('#form1');
$('<input type="text" required="required" />').val('08').appendTo('#form2');
```

HTML:

```
<form id="form1"><input type="submit" value="Click me"/></form>
<form id="form2"><input type="submit" value="Click me"/></form>
```

Fiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/x7aRt/1/

Comment: Just tried in the jsFiddle, seems to have no effect.

Comment: Ya, just tested it too

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x7aRt/3/  Setting val() after clone() method, i guess it is not what you expect

Comment: Then this works: `$('<input type="text" required="required" />').val('08').clone().val(function(){return this.value}).appendTo('#form1');` but damn weird

Comment: Hmm, that might be the thing I'm looking for. Problem is I don't know that value after the clone, but setting it back to it's own value might work. Lemme check...

Comment: That works, if you create an answer, I can accept it :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug in chrome (webkit?) or related maybe to jQuery.

To validate input, looks like you need to re-set value after cloning it, doesn't make much sense but...

```
$('<input type="text" required="required" />').val('08').clone().val(function(){return this.value}).appendTo('#form1');
```